# kmalloc function and protection (READ,WRITE,EXEC)

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

I have a question regarding kmalloc function (found in the linux kernel) and protection:

1. What is the default protection (write/read/exec) for an allocated memory created by kmalloc?
2. How can I change the allocated region's protection? (from kernel mode)
3. How can I find all kernel allocated memory and its protection?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. The memory allocated by kmalloc is readable, writable and executable by default, IIRC.

Comment: 2. See [set_memory_nx()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=set_memory_nx) and [set_memory_ro()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=set_memory_ro), these may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kmalloc is just an interface to the REAL memory manager, the kmem [cache allocator](http://jikos.jikos.cz/Kmalloc_Internals.html).