# Virtual memory protection - Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtual-memory

First of all - my goal is to allow execution of memory allocated by kmalloc.
Given the following code snippet (Assume that size of function foo is given):

```
void foo()
{
      printk("Nothing that matters.\n");
}

void bar()
{
     void* s = kmalloc(PAGE_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL);
     memcpy(s, foo, SIZE OF FOO);
     void (*f)(void) = (void(*)(void))s;
     f();

}
```

The following code yields a gp because i don't have execution permissions for the kmalloced allocated page.

I solved the same issue @ OSX using:

```
kern_return_t
mach_vm_protect(
mach_port_name_t task,
mach_vm_address_t address,
mach_vm_size_t size,
boolean_t set_maximum,
vm_prot_t new_protection);
```

and now I'm trying to find a way of solving this issue in Linux.

I tried the following:

```
    pgd_t* pgd = pgd_offset(mm, address);
    pmd_t* pmd = pmd_offset(pgd, address);  
    pte_t pte = /**pte_offset_map(pmd, address)*/*pte_offset_kernel(pmd, address);
    pte_mkexec(pte);
```

But no luck so far. If anyone has faced the same issue in the past, I would love to hear some suggestions / solutions to the problem.

Comment: Hi, a similar questions was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347858/kmalloc-function-and-protection-read-write-exec.  Hope it helps.